# Is there a Ruby equivalent to PHP's extract?

Tags: php, ruby, hash, extract

I can create a block that will extract hash elements and turn them into local variables, but I'm wondering if a native method already exists. Something like this:

```
extract({ :foo => 'bar', :foo2 => 'bar2' })
puts foo  # 'bar'
puts foo2 # 'bar2'
```

Note that the keys are private, and that the scope needs to stay local.

Comment: Yes, dragons, true. In this case, less dragons because all private and local, and dealing with fairly obnoxious hash var names + tons of members. extract not necessary but nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get close:

```
bar, bar2 = h.values_at :foo, :foo2
```

Or I suppose we could extend Hash to extract into instance variables:

```
class Hash
  def extract o
    each { |k, v| o.instance_variable_set '@' + k.to_s, v }
  end
end

h.extract self

p [@foo, @foo2]
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this one – good to know, thank you – but with a bunch of keys it wouldn't be enough of a savings to be worth it, especially since if you change a key name, you then change it twice in this assignment and again wherever you've used it. You could genericize the local variable names but that's not quite what I'm hoping for. May not be possible, in which case...so be it!

Comment: Ok, I've updated it with a completely automated approach, but it violates your local-scope rule.

Comment: Handy! I hope this question never gets fully answered because I'm learning all kinds of tricks. :-)

Comment: Wow! Ruby is so much better and cleaner than PHP. Loving this method. Using parallel assignment kind of forces you to pull out just what you need rather than how PHP just barfs everything out, which is disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each` method to iterate through each `key=>value` pair:

```
{ :foo => 'bar', :foo2 => 'bar2' }.each do |key, value|
  print key,"\t",value,"\n"
end
```

Outputs:

```
 foo     bar
 foo2    bar2
```

Comment: Thanks, Teddy. I know I can do it in a block. Just looking for a short-hand method.