# Interchanging hash keys and local variable names in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Ruby equivalent to PHP's extract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428433/is-there-a-ruby-equivalent-to-phps-extract)

Is there any way to take a Ruby hash such as:

```
myhash = {a: 12, b:24, c:36}
```

and convert this into a set of local variables (short of manually doing the assignments, obviously)?  The result should be just as if I had executed the statements:

```
a = 12
b = 24
c = 36
```

Similarly, can I take a set of defined local variables and make a hash where the keys are the variable names and the values are the variable values (again, short of writing out the hash literally)?  I haven't seen anything like this before so I'm guessing the answer is no, but it would be nice...

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, there is almost certainly a better way. Can you provide more info so we can suggest a different solution?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek I'm finding myself passing medium-sized hashes as arguments fairly frequently.  It's cumbersome and bloating to have to access the values stored in these hashes through the hash syntax all the time-- I was thinking I could 'unpack' (or extract) the hash inside my method, do whatever manipulation I set out to do, then repack it when returning it.

Comment: I suspect the answer is to embrace OO. If the hashes are options, pull them out and set them on ivars. If you're actually manipulating them, then there's a good chance you should be using objects instead of hashes (instead of holding data in the hash, the object holds it. instead of manipulating the hash's data, you tell the object to manipulate its own data). Difficult to give better advice without seeing more code.

Comment: This works for me (but it's hacky):

myhash = {a: 12, b: 24, c: 36}

myhash.each do |k, v|
  Kernel.send(:define_method, k, Proc.new {v})
end

Comment: If you prefer not to access method arguments through a hash, then maybe you shouldn't be passing them as a hash in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You probably know this already, but for the record: if you are willing to make instance variables instead of locals then this function will work:

```
def f x
  x.each do |k, v|
    instance_variable_set "@#{k}", v
  end
end

f :abc => 123, 'def' => 456

> @abc
=> 123 
> @def
=> 456
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of this stuff with [`Kernel.eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3

local_variables.grep(/^[a-z]\w*/)
=> ["a", "b", "c"]

# Map local variables to hash
@h = Hash[local_variables.grep(/^[a-z]\w*/).map { |var| [var, eval(var)] }]     
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}

# Map hash to local variables
@b = binding
@h.each { |k,v| eval("#{k}_new = #{v + 100}", @b) }

local_variables.grep(/^[a-z]\w*/)
=> ["a", "b", "c", "a_new", "b_new", "c_new"]

[a_new, b_new, c_new]
=> [101, 102, 103]
```

Comment: `"#{usual_code_injection_warning}"`

Comment: This won't work in Ruby 1.9, as the the scope of any local variables declared in an `eval` is limited to the `eval` itself.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Wow I didn't know that. Any idea why that is? Seems like binding could be used to adjust scope like in 1.8. Strange design decision :-(

Comment: @Casper Probably security—it's not a very good idea, after all. [Here's a brief reply by Matz about it](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673#685906).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Ok thanks. However as a programmer I'm not very fond of this type of forced hand-holding (not that that helps here very much :)). But OK..there's not many instances where you'd really need to do anything like this. Started to wonder how IRB actually works in 1.9. How can you build a REPL without this functionality. Hmm.

Comment: Anyone interested: this is how `irb` works in 1.9: `@irb_binding = eval("def irb_binding; binding; end; irb_binding")`. All `eval` calls are evaluated inside the `irb_binding` context. That keeps local variables contained in the same context through the whole IRB session.